# Proof $M(T)_{.,k} = M(v_k)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I working on Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right and I found this problem.
M(T) is defined to be a matrix representation of a linear map of T in $L(V,W)$ with respect to a given basis $v_1,...,v_n$ and $w_1,...,w_m$.
Let $v \in V$ then $M(v)$ is a n-by-1 matrix of $a_1,...,a_n$ such that $v=a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n$.
And $M(v_k)$ is computed with respect to $w_1,...,w_n$.
Which means $M(v_k)$ is a m-by-1 matrix $(c_1 ... c_m)^T$ such that $c_1w_1+...+c_mw_m=v_k$. How could this be possible when $v_k$ is in V?

Comment: I think you are talking about linear maps $T:V\rightarrow W$.  Then it sounds like it really means $c_1w_1 + ... c_mw_m = T(v_k)$. Then it sounds like you really have $M(T)$ is a matrix with each row a $c$ vector.

Comment: So $M:L\rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{m,n}$ is a function that maps a linear transformation to a matrix, so a given linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$ gets mapped to a matrix $M(T)$.

Comment: So you mean this is a typo error in the book? The author really means $M(T(v_k))$ after all?

Comment: I would need to see the book.  But if we define $M:L\rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{m,n}$, then writing $M(T(v_k))$ does not make sense because $T(v_k)$ is a vector in $w$, whereas the $M(\cdot)$ function needs a linear transformation as input, not a vector as input, i.e., $M(T)$ makes sense.

Comment: Either $M$ is the matrix associated to a particular linear map, once the isomorphism between $L(V,W)$ and $F^{m,n}$ has been fixed, and then $M(v_k)$ makes sense, or $M$ is the isomorphism, for any element $T\in L(V,W)$ you have a matrix $M(T)$, and then $M(T)(v_k)$ makes sense, but $M(v_k)$ does not

Comment: @JoseBrox : I don't think $M(T)(v_k)$ would make sense since the matrix requires a vector in $\mathbb{F}^n$ as input, not an abstract vector in $V$ as input. So you would first represent $v_1$ as $(1,0,0,...,0)$, $v_2$ as $(0,1,0,0,...,0)$, and so on. So $M(T)(1,0,0...0)$ is a c-vector.

Comment: $M$ is a matrix associated to a particular linear map. The problem is given that $M(v_k)$ makes sense. It's just that the equation does not make sense to me.

Comment: There seems to be a typo somewhere in the book. It is hard to know exactly where without seeing the book itself. Note that $M(v_k)$ does not make sense, for the same reason that $M(T(v_k))$ does not make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really was a typo. Specifically, $\mathcal{M}(v_k)$ should be $\mathcal{M}(Tv_k)$ on lines 2, 4, 7, and 9 of page 85 of the third edition of my book *Linear Algebra Done Right*.

My apologies for the confusion caused by this error. I tried hard to eliminate all typos from the book, but a few slipped through.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out! It's really a typo. I tried $M(T(v_k))$ and the equation fit perfectly.

Comment: That does not make sense since the $M(\cdot)$ function needs a linear transformation as input.  I think it means $M(T)e_k$ where $e_k=(0,0,...,1,0,0,...0)$.  So $M(T)$ is a matrix and $M(T)e_k$ is the $k$th column of that matrix, which is hte $c$-vector associated with expressing $T(v_k)$ in terms of the basis vectors for $W$.

Comment: Yes. But later on, the author also add a definition for M mapping on a vector space. And thus there is this equation. But what doesn't make sense to me is that $v_k$ has to be expressed as a linear combination of a basis of W while $v_k$ is in V.

Comment: This is used to prove $M(Tv)=M(T)M(v)$ which expresses linear maps as matrix multiplication.

Comment: Then, it sounds like we really have a map $M:V\rightarrow \mathbb{F}^m$ .  I wonder if the book distinguishes $M(\cdot)$ from $Mat(\cdot)$.

Comment: I found the book here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=2ahUKEwi_y6jL5dPdAhXIy4MKHVDHC1gQFjAIegQIBxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2F148.206.53.84%2Ftesiuami%2FS_pdfs%2FLinear%2520Algebra%2520Done%2520Right.pdf&usg=AOvVaw36zAy7BuRknGV2Qzig0EQZ  what equation are you referring to? I do notice that equations (3.15) and and (3.13) use $\mathcal{M}(\cdot)$ informally to mean "the matrix of" but you can plug different types of inputs (vectors, maps, and so on) into it, so it does not formally define $\mathcal{M}:(domain)\rightarrow(range)$ as I expected.

Comment: It's the equation 3.64